# Writing an abstract factory for SwiftUI views

Tags: swift, oop, swiftui

I am trying to write an abstract factory (protocol is `Factory`) for SwiftUI views. The goal is to read some settings and based on this settings instantiate a concrete factory which produces concrete views. The known factories are encapsulated in an enum (`FactoryType`) which also provides a method to get the concrete factory for a case.

Now some wrapping view gets passed a factory type and queries the known factories enum for a concrete factory based on the given type. It will use the concrete factory to build its view.

The problem is every function that returns a concrete factory based on a switch statement needs to specify its return type as `any Factory`. When this "any" factory is used inside the body view builder of a view the compiler throws the error `Type 'any View' cannot conform to 'View'`.

I know that at compile time the compiler needs to know the concrete type which is used. I also know that with some generics magic a lot can be done, but I am out of ideas.

Is there any solution to this problem apart from doing the switch statement inside the view builder of the wrapping view? (I don’t want this solution because whenever you add a new factory type you also need to change the view which is not very clean code.)

I prepared some example code to illustrate the problem:

```swift
import SwiftUI

protocol Factory {
    associatedtype V: View
    
    func createView() -> V  
}

struct ViewA: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("view A")
    }
}

struct ViewB: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("view B")
    }    
}

struct AFactory: Factory {
    func createView() -> ViewA {
        return ViewA()
    }  
}

struct BFactory: Factory {
    func createView() -> ViewB {
        return ViewB()
    }  
}

enum FactoryType {
    case a
    case b
    
    var factory: any Factory {
        switch self {
        case .a:
            return AFactory()
        case .b:
            return BFactory()
        }
    }
}

struct ClientView: View {
    let factoryType: FactoryType
    
    var body: some View {        
        let factory = factoryType.factory
        factory.createView() // error: Type 'any View' cannot conform to 'View'
    }
}

struct ClientViewUnwanted: View {
    let factoryType: FactoryType
    
    var body: some View {
        switch factoryType {
        case .a:
            AFactory().createView()
        case .b:
            BFactory().createView()
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: Why overcomplicate this with `Factory`s? How about just add a `some View` property to `FactoryType`? Let that property give you the view directly. Because then you can use `@ViewBuilder`, which allows you to return different views in a switch statement like this.

Comment: "I don’t want this solution because whenever you add a new factory type you also need to change the view which is not very clean code." Are you saying your current code is cleaner? You still have to add a new switch case whenever you add a new factory type.

Comment: It’s about separation of concerns. Why should a view know about some new concrete factory?
Adding this new factory to `FactoryType` is only one place to change and it is the place where one would expect this change.

Comment: Regarding your first comment, @Sweeper, this is not the most beautiful solution – it still is not very good in separating concerns – but I’ll give it a try. Thanks. :)

Comment: SwiftUI certainly expects to know that concrete factory. View builders work on concrete type.

Comment: You should watch “Demystify SwiftUI” you are going down something similar to “AnyView” and this is highly discouraged. SwiftUI needs concrete types.

Comment: I tried it and it doesn’t work. I added `var view: some View` to `FactoryType` which switches over `self` and returns a concrete view. This results in an error about opaque return type and the underlying returns don’t match it. `@ViewBuilder` in front of `var view: some View` doesn't help.

Comment: I get what you are trying to do but SwiftUI just doesn’t allow it. SwiftUI is not like other UI frameworks it was created for fast development and maximum compatibility. It isn’t necessarily efficient and it isn’t flexible. It’s improving with every iteration but it has a long way to go.

Comment: Using some sort of OO design (ab)using protocols isn't really how you should design code with SwiftUI – and (IMHO) also not even with Swift. Your explanatory example would be a collection of code smells. Instead, with SwiftUI you should embrace _explicitness_ and thus get type-safety and clarity. Well, you _may_ have a factory function `(value) -> AnyView` which is setup in the SwiftUI environment at some _configuration location_ which for example decouples a concrete Source view from a concrete Target view in a navigation scenario – but what does it actually buy you?

Comment: @CouchDeveloper Separation of concerns. Module ClientView do not have to depend on ViewA and ViewB if we could use the factory pattern

Answer (score 1):

Instead of complicating things with the `Factory` protocols, `FactoryType` can return the view directly:

```
enum FactoryType {
    case a
    case b
    
    @ViewBuilder
    var view: some View {
        switch self {
        case .a:
            ViewA()
        case .b:
            ViewB()
        }
    }
}
```

`view` will now return a concrete type (a very complicated one created by `ViewBuilder`, probably starts with `_ConditionalContent<...>`).

Note the lack of `return` statements. If you add them in, we would not be able to enjoy `@ViewBuilder`. Result builders work on the *expressions* you put in the function/property body.

Comment: Maybe the configuration of the view comes from a json (or something else) and the factory allow more flexibility over the content of ViewA or ViewB by provident the specific ways of creating the objects

Comment: In the meantime I got that working too. But I don’t like this approach. First my factory needs to produce a lot more views. That would mean I have to repeat the switch case in every view producing function, which would lead to a lot of changes when a new type is added. Avoiding exactly that was the whole reason why I wanted a factory in the first place. (In clean code this is "replace conditional with polymorphism".) And second I don’t like that a non view type returns something view related. This is against separation of concerns.

Comment: @RayWojciechowski You refer to OO concepts. In OO, the switch would be a code smell. You would use derived classes and polymorphism to fix it. And OO would require your code to adhere to a bag of other OO constraints, like Liskov substitution principle and more ([SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID)).  However, SwiftUI is not based on OO design concepts. UIKit is. OO is, let me say in a state of "lessons learned". You'd be better off doing it the Swift(UI) way, it's definitely the better tool and not just for UI code.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper that’s why I asked this question. I really have trouble to approach this problem in a clean, maintainable and extendable way. I don’t see what the "Swift(UI) way" would be to tackle this problem.

Comment: @RayWojciechowski A view is simply a _function of state_.  And _state_ is a trivial data type (not an object with relations).Hence, it's a question how you realise this "state management". In SwiftUI you have the tools to implement this, like environment, ObservableObject, `@Sate` etc., but you need to extend these tools with your own architecture to realise it. You may look into [TCA](https://github.com/pointfreeco/swift-composable-architecture) which is a framework specifically designed for state management and where you can implement very complex apps.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper, thanks for the TCA link! I will definitely will have a look at it. I am not sure whether this will do anything to solve my current problem, but it sure is a nice way of managing state. Although it is quite heavy artillery. ;)

Comment: @RayWojciechowski TCA has nothing to do with your problem. It does not tackle factory pattern at all.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not saying that the best swiftUI solution however you could wrap your view return by the factory into the swiftUI type eraser AnyView like so :

```
enum FactoryType {
    case a
    case b
    
    var view: some View {
        switch self {
            case .a:
                return AnyView(AFactory().createView())
            case .b:
                return AnyView(BFactory().createView())
        }
    }
}

struct ClientView: View {
    let factoryType: FactoryType
    
    var body: some View {
        factoryType.view
    }
}
```