# ERROR: Type 'any View' cannot conform to 'View'

Tags: swift, swiftui

I can't seem to wrap my head around this, tried everything, nothing works. I have bunch of Structs and each struct has its view struct also they are associated with enum. Idea is to have a helper function that could return struct by selecting enum ant it works but not for the view:

```swift
// Protocol that all structs conform to
protocol MyStructProtocol {
  associatedtype Body: View 
  func getView() -> Body 
  func myCustomFunc() -> String
}

// Enum for different structs
public enum MyStructs {
  case MyStruct1
  // More cases
}


struct MyStruct1: MyStructProtocol {
  func getView() -> MyStruct1View {
    return MyStruct1View()
  }
   
  func myCustomFunc() -> String {
    return "MyStruct1"
  }
}


// View for MyStruct1 
struct MyStruct1View: View {
  var body: some View {
    Text("MyStruct1 View")
  }
}

// MyStruct2 etc..

// Helper function to get struct based on enum value
func getStruct(for enumValue: MyStructs) -> any MyStructProtocol {
  switch enumValue {
  case .MyStruct1:
    return MyStruct1()
  // other cases
  }
}

// Usage in SwiftUI
struct TestView: View {
  let selectedEnum = MyStructs.MyStruct1
   
  var body: some View {
    let selectedStruct = getStruct(for: selectedEnum)
    return selectedStruct.getView() // ERROR: Type 'any View' cannot conform to 'View'
  }
}
```

It only works if I wrap view in AnyView, but I heard it's a bad thing so looking for better solution.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77022504/5133585). This is not a good design for SwiftUI. You should not have something like `MyStructProtocol` in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but I heard [AnyView is] a bad thing so looking for better solution.

The goal of SwiftUI is to resolve the entire View hierarchy at compile-time. The reason AnyView is a bad solution is that it cannot do that. Also, any other technique you use to avoid resolving the entire View hierarchy at compile-time is equally bad.

The typical solution for this kind of problem is `@ViewBuilder`. It makes it easy to convert a `switch` statement into `some View`. To use that, replace `getStruct` with `getView`:

```
// Helper function to get View based on enum value
@ViewBuilder
func getView(for enumValue: MyStructs) -> some View {
    switch enumValue {
    case .MyStruct1:
        MyStruct1().getView()
        // other cases
    }
}
```

And then you can use it:

```
    var body: some View {
        getView(for: selectedEnum)
    }
```

I believe you'll find with this approach that `MyStructProtocol` is probably unneeded.

That said, I'd probably consider doing it this way instead:

```
public enum MyStructs {
    case MyStruct1
    // More cases

    @ViewBuilder
    var view: some View {
        switch self {
        case .MyStruct1: MyStruct1View()
        }
    }
}

struct TestView: View {
    let selectedEnum = MyStructs.MyStruct1

    var body: some View {
        selectedEnum.view
    }
}
```